# Moving to Munich

Tags: germany

I have been looking at jobs in Germany and i stumbled across one in Munich that i am very interested in. However i heard that Munich is very expensive in comparison to other cities like Berlin. Also i didn't understand a few things concerning the tax system in Germany. Assuming i get paid 50,000 Euros per year gross, how much will i be able to retain post rent and taxes?

I have read quite a bit about the tax system and living expenses but that either didn't provide enough information or were inconsistent.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are unmarried, have no children, do not pay church tax (just say "no religion" during registration at the local office)  - you would have ~2550 € euro monthly net ([here is the calculation tool](https://www.brutto-netto-rechner.info/)).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When you say net you mean only after taxes right? so rent and living costs are unincluded?

Comment: Obviously, not. No one knows how much you would pay for rent and other living costs.

Answer (score 4):

I am in the same boat as yours, let me share my experience so far.

- First thing you need to know is your net salary post-tax. Please use [this](https://www.brutto-netto-rechner.info/gehalt/gross_net_calculator_germany.php) salary calculator to understand what is your take home. This tool also talks about different tax classes.
- Then you should try to get an idea of your monthly expenses. I am using [this](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/) tool for that purpose.

Also, note that rents are sky high in Munich (basically everywhere in Germany) and searching for them on various websites will give an exact idea of the costs. If you are planning to relocate with your family - please factor in other costs like child education and travel pass for your spouse.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for your reply. I am going alone and i am unmarried so hopefully that would save me a bit of money.

Comment: I wouldn't say rents are sky high everywhere in Germany, but in Munich they are and moreover, in the surroundings of Munich they are basically just as high if not higher (towards the Alps).

Answer (score 1):

Taxes in Germany are pretty high. quick-and-dirty approach is that after taxes you get only half of what you earned. For correct answer you need to fill in details, like where you live (every state in German has different calculation), do you have children (people without children has to pay more) etc.

www.howtogermany.com has a lot of useful information. For example about topics like [cultural differences](https://www.howtogermany.com/pages/living.html), [paying taxes](https://www.howtogermany.com/pages/germantaxes.html) and [insurance](https://www.howtogermany.com/pages/insurance.html) (in Germany health insurance and liability insurance for motor vehicles are mandatory. You also should think about third-party private liability insurance (Haftpflichtversicherung)).